# How to get an uri from a rdf file when inserting data with jena query?

Tags: java, sparql, rdf, jena, rdfs

I'm using jena to execute a sparql query for inserting data in a rdf file:

```
String queryString = "PREFIX kb:<http://protege.stanford.edu/kb#> \n"
            + "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>\n"
            + "INSERT DATA\n"
            + "{\n"
            + "kb:######## rdf:type kb:Virtual_Entity;\n"
            + "kb:" + property + " '" + value + "'.\n"
            + "}";
```

I need to put an unique uri identifier where the '######' is.

I used protege to insert some data manually and every uri is generated by protege with "modelo_ClassXX" where XX and incremented number.

Is there a way to query the rdf or event the rdfs(schema file) to give the next uri or to put something in the very that can generate it automatically?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're asking for an algorithm for minting new URI? The way RDF works, you're free to choose whatever you like, e.g. use current date+time, a random UUID, a sequential number or something meaningful. Since RDF makes no assumptions on the syntax of URI, it should be irrelevant how they look, as long as they are different for different entities and valid URI.

Comment: **"Is there a way to query the rdf or event the rdfs(schema file) to give the next uri or to put something in the very that can generate it automatically?"** As kba notes, if you just need legal IRIs, you can use just about anything.  If you want to keep using the sequence numbers from protégé, you'll need a query to figure out what number to use.  Since you're executing this from java, you might also want to consider using a prepared query so that you can make your query **insert data { ?uri a kb:VirtualEntity ; ?property ?value }** and just object those values.

Comment: What  query can I use to figure out what number to use in the URI to use the same sequence number form protege??